# Python - Numba : How can I pass a @jitclass class to a property type in the specs of another @jitclass class?

Tags: python, numba

I have a class `OrderBook` that is `@jitclass`.
I want to declare a class `Position` that contains a `last_ob` property, of type `OrderBook`. `Position` is a `@jitclass` as well.

```
@jitclass([
    ('instrument', types.string),
    ('size', float32),
    ('avg_price', float32),
    ('last_quote', OrderBook),
])
class Position:
    ...
```

However, Numba says :

```
spec values should be Numba type instances, got <class 'numba.experimental.jitclass.base.OrderBook'>
```

What is strange is that I can pass with no problem a list of OrderBook like that :

```
@jitclass([
    ('instrument', types.string),
    ('size', float32),
    ('avg_price', float32),
    ('last_quote', types.ListType(OrderBook)),
])
class Position:
    ...
```

Compiles successfully. If I can compile a property of type `List of a @jitclass class`, I can probably compile a property that is the Numba class itself. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
('last_quote', numba.typeof(OrderBook("init_your_class"))),
```